# How to schedule timer for specific date and time in android?

Tags: java, android

eventPoller.schedule(new EventPoller(adapter),dateOfEvent , 100000);

- I want to schedule remainder for particular date and time by using TimerTask. i am doing this    without broadcast receiver as I just want to schedule it and show some notification as remainder to user.
- so please suggest me, how can I pass the date and time both in this method so that Notification will come on that exact time and date.
- is there any other way to remind events to user other than broadcast receiver?????

please suggest any solution asap.............

Comment: Use AlarmManager : http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-alarm-manager_31.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use alarmManager.

Keep in mind that you need to set alarmManager every time user restarts phone. This means you need to implement BroadcastReciver and set it there.

If you need an example in can post it for you.

Comment: yeahh... If i need it. please post an example so that I can implement code by referring it..

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml  <receiver
            android:name="package.name.alarm.AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: AlarmReceiver.java (extends BroadcastReceiver) private PendingIntent sender;
    private AlarmManager am;
    private Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

Comment: if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()))
        {

            am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);

         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (c.getTimeInMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);