# Is there a way to schedule a timer to start on a specific date?

Tags: java, android

I want make the **count down** timer to start on a specific time in future when it arrives.

Here's the code I wrote for now. I need some kind of listener to time that will activate the timer when time is arrived. The app is generally about tenders with starting times and ending times.

```
     CountDownTimer c = new CountDownTimer(tender.getTime(), 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {



            long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished);
            millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days);

            long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished);
            millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);

            long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished);
            millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);

            long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished);


            if (days == 0) {
                if (hours == 0) {
                    time.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds);
                } else {
                    time.setText(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
                }
            } else if (hours == 0) {
                time.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds);
            } else {
                time.setText(days + " days , " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
            }



        }

        public void onFinish() {
            time.setText("over");
        }

    };


    if(tender.calcTimer(tender.getStartTender(),tender.getStartTime())>=0){
        time.setText("didn't start yet");
    }
    else if(tender.getTime()<=0){
        time.setText("over");
    }
    if (time.getText().toString().equals(null)) {

        c.start();

    }
```

Comment: Use alarm manager

Comment: JobScheduler API is better

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to schedule timer for specific date and time in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020910/how-to-schedule-timer-for-specific-date-and-time-in-android)

Comment: take a look to the new [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

Comment: This timer located in an expandble list adapter, i don't know how to call it from the alarm manager.